# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are some integers, then $a^2 - 4b$ does not equal $2$.

Tags: integers

> Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are some integers, then $a^2 - 4b$ does not equal $2$.

How do I prove this, I tried using contradiction but I'm not sure how I can contradict this statement?

Comment: Is it possile if a is odd?  Is it possible if a is even.

Comment: It doesnt say anything about it being odd or even in the question

Comment: So? That doesn't mean *you* can't say anything about it being odd or even.  So, again.  What happens if a is odd?  What happens if a is even?

Comment: Contradiction:  Let $a^2 - 4b = 2$ then $a^2 = 4b + 2 = 2(2b + 1)$ so $a$ is even.  Let $a = 2c$.  $4c^2 = 2(2b + 1)$ so $2c^2 = 2b + 1$.  Hmmmmm.....

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use congruences. Such an equality would imply $2$ is a square modulo $4$. Write the list of all squares modulo $4$ and see if $2$ is among them.

*Some details:*

Remember two integers are congruent modulo $4$ if they have the same remainder when divided by $4$. This is equivalent to ‘one of them is equal to the other, pus a multiple of $4$’.

So $a^2-4b=2\iff a^2=2+4b\iff a^2\equiv 2\mod 4$.

Now the classes of congruence modulo $4$ are $0$, $\pm1$, $2$, and the relation of congruence is compatible with addition and multiplication. Thus the clsses of congruence of the squares are

- $0^2=0$;
- $(\pm1)^2=1$;
- $2^2=4\equiv0$.

Neither $-1$ nor $2$ are in the list of (congruence classes) of squares modulo 4: we proved $2$ and  $-1$ are not squares modulo $4$.

Comment: I have little understanding of modulos and where and how to use them. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: @Chance Gordon: I've added details. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality can be rewritten as $a^2\neq 4b+2= 2(2b+1)$.
Note that $2b+1$ is always an odd number whatever be $b$.
SO your question boils down to showing $a^2$ can never be double an odd number.

When $a$ is odd its square cannot be double of any number, being odd again.

When $a$ is even $ a^2$ will be an even number squared, that is $2m\times 2m$ which is double of an even number. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction: Write as $(a+2b)(a-2b)=2$. Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, $a+2b$ and $a-2b$ are also integers. Therefore either $a+2b=2$ and $a-2b=1$, or $a+2b=1$ and $a-2b=2$ (or $-2$ and $-1$ or $-1$ and $-2$). There are $4$ pairs of simultaneous equations that could be true, however solving gives either: $a=3/2$, $b=\pm 1/4$ or $a=-3/2$, $b=\pm 1/4$. Any of these solutions contradicts that $a$ and $b$ were integers.

Comment: $(a+2b)(a-2b) = a^2 - 4b^2 \ne a^2 - 4b$.